# How can I perform a find() and also return entities before and after the found entity?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to perform a query where I get return an object for one of the records in my `SQL` table. In this case, it is a `DbImageModel` object (*see code below*).
The code below works great to return a single entity based on the query criteria:

```
s.ImageTag == imageTag
```

but I need to find a way to return the entities **before** and **after** the current found entity as well. Or at least the `imageTag` values for the **before** and **after** entities. Is this possible?

My code is as follows:

```
using (UsersDbContext ctx = new UsersDbContext())
{
    try
    {
        DbImageModel image = ctx.Images.Include(i => i.Application)
              .OrderBy(c => c.ImageId)
              .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ImageTag == imageTag);
        // Do something with image

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();  // For debugging
    }
}
```

I should also mention that my database relationships are set up as many `DbImageModel` objects to a single `DbApplicationModel`. And there are many `DbApplicationModel` objects for a single `DbUserModel` object.

This doesn't sound like it should be a new issue for developers, but I haven't been able to find any references that discuss a way to do this.

**UPDATE:**

I added an order by. My question still applies.

Comment: Define **before** and **after**

Comment: Define before and after?

Comment: And I even did it with bold markup :)

Comment: Yeah. Note that the request makes zero sense UNLESS you add an ORDER BY - sql result returns are randomly ordered, so before and after make no sense, unless you ask for a specific order.

Comment: I'd suggest adding some sort of sorting to your query as well to guarantee that your underlying data source doesn't change it's default order over time.

Comment: Before and after meaning if I was to return all the entities in the SQL table, then the the record 'before' and 'after' the record matching `imageTag`. @TomTom. I think you are correct here. I do need an ORDER BY for it to make sense. But adding that, my question should still apply.

Comment: @Brett You've encountered the most interesting topic there is, proximity, welcome :) If you have some index you can use that, and go +1, -1 on that, but no, there is no way of doing this.

Comment: @flindeberg Is there a way to get the index of a returned entity? Note I added an `OrderBy` to my query.

Comment: @Brett Well, not a "natural" way, but if you want behaviour like this have a look at for example MongoDB and the `$near` concept: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near. Relational databases are not made for "near" or proximities in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ImageId` is always incremental, you could select the items within a set range of the discovered ImageId:

```
    DbImageModel images = 
        from i in ctx.Images.Include(i => i.Application)
        let match = ctx.Images.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ImageTag == imageTag)
        where i.ImageId < match.ImageId + 1 &&
            i.ImageId > match.ImageId - 1
        order by i.ImageId
        select i;
```

However, I imagine you can't always assume this to be the case. For example, if you ever allow an image to be deleted, there would be gaps. Chances are, your best bet is to use multiple round-trips. First find the image using the code you provided, then:

```
DbImageModel imageAfter = ctx.Images.Include(i => i.Application)
    .OrderBy(i => i.ImageId)
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ImageId > image.ImageId);
DbImageModel imageBefore = ctx.Images.Include(i => i.Application)
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.ImageId)
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ImageId < image.ImageId);
```

It's possible that you could come up with some kind of convoluted query to yield all of these in one round-trip, but its complexity could end up making it take longer than these three round-trips combined.

Comment: Looks like the approach I just posted :-) Your answer is clear and succinct, so I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: depends on how busy the db server is, it may be necessary to lock the database or complete those two reads in one transaction while executing those two queries so you won't get caught in a case where when the "first" is read, then a new one is inserted that caused the order to be out of sync.

Comment: @RayCheng: Since the ImageId property is an auto-incrementing ID value, there shouldn't be anything inserted between existing values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question here. Because, **YES**, there is a way - at least with multiple queries - which I would like to avoid, but oh well.

```
using (UsersDbContext ctx = new UsersDbContext())
{
    try
    {
        DbImageModel image = ctx.Images.Include(i => i.Application)
              .OrderBy(c => c.ImageId)
              .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ImageTag == imageTag);

        DbImageModel previousImage = ctx.Images.OrderBy(c => c.ImageId)
              .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ImageId < image.ImageId);

        DbImageModel nextImage = ctx.Images.OrderBy(c => c.ImageId)
              .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ImageId > image.ImageId);

        // Do something with image(s)

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();  // For debugging
    }
}
```

Note: `ImageId` is the SQL auto incremented id for the record.

Comment: Oh my - that is 3 queries dude ;)

Answer (score -2):

Let's ignore the fact that before / after make no sense in a query taht returns data in an undefined order (as any SQL does - the server dcan return the data in any order it wants unless you define an order, which the example does not).

No, no way.

You basically will have to implement your own extension method to do that. This is a rare enough request that they did not embed that into the standard SQL.

You HAVE to enumerate over all data (first can be done in the database with a TOP 1 - but that means you only get one row to the client) which will have a performance impact.

If you ahve before / afer in something like an ID - then you could use a join and get the bale join the one with ID -1 join the one with ID +1.... but that is a special case.